# How to optimize Django's model's string representation database hits in browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to optimize my API and noticed that the browsable API is responsible for N+1 queries. This only happens when I add the parent-class in the child's `__str__` method.

Comparison using django-debug-toolbar:

- `f"{self.name} ({self.client.name})"`: default 531.44 ms (370 queries including 358 similar and 348 duplicates )
- `f"{self.name}"`: default 130.54 ms (24 queries including 12 similar and 2 duplicates )

My (simplified) models are the following:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    """Model for a Client."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, verbose_name="Company name")

    class Meta:
        """Set ordering."""

        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a good string representation for a Client."""
        return f"{self.name}"


class Budget(models.Model):
    """Model for representing a budget of a client."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Budget name")
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="budgets", on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        """Set ordering."""

        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["client", "name"], name="unique_client_budget_name_combination")]
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a good string representation of a Budget."""
        # self.client.name triggers multiple database hits
        return f"{self.name} ({self.client.name})"
```

This is the view:

```
class BudgetCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Overview of all Budgets. Uses one serializer for creating and another for displaying."""

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """Use the display_serializer_class for displaying the model instance."""
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            return self.display_serializer_class
        return self.serializer_class

    queryset = Budget.objects.all().select_related("client")
    serializer_class = BudgetSerializer
    display_serializer_class = BudgetDisplaySerializer
```

I have also tried using `select_related("client")` in the view, but this did not help. It seems like the browsable API is not using the view's queryset.

How can I make the browsable API make more efficient? Is that even possible?

Comment: Show mentioned API endpoint and view code.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I added the view code. What do you mean with API Endpoint? An example of the JSON? Or the browsable API? Or Both?

Answer (score 0):

Override `get_queryset` method

> If the serializer_class used in the generic view spans orm relations, leading to an n+1 problem, you could optimize your queryset in this method using select_related and prefetch_related. To get more information about n+1 problem and use cases of the mentioned methods refer to related section in django documentation.

[Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself)

Instead of `queryset = Budget.objects.all().select_related("client")` use

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Budget.objects.all().select_related("client")
```

Comment: Sadly, this did not change anything. It is the same as before.